# Generate XPath of Line Differences in XML File with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

I have two XML files and I want to compare the differences in PowerShell and output the XPath of the lines which are different.

My code currently reads the two XML files with Get-Content, then compares them with Compare-Object.  This allows me to iterate through each line with a foreach loop and output the lines that have changed to a file:

```
# Create content streams from XML files
$referenceContent = Get-Content ".\temp\ReferenceElement.xml"
$differenceContent = Get-Content ".\temp\DifferenceElement.xml"

# Exclude lines with these strings
$excludePattern = ".*<id>.*|.*ID>.*|.*id=.*|.*?xml.*|.*xmlns.*"

# Compare contents of XML files
$comparedLines = Compare-Object $referenceContent $differenceContent -IncludeEqual | Sort-Object { $_.InputObject.ReadCount }

# Annotate each line in the output file
$lineNumber = 0
$comparedLines | foreach {
    if($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
    {
        $lineNumber = $_.InputObject.ReadCount
    }

    if($_.InputObject -notmatch $excludePattern)
    {
        if($_.SideIndicator -ne "==")
        {
            if($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=")
            {
                $lineOperation = "Removed"
            }
            elseif($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
            {
                $lineOperation = "Added"
            }
           
            $results = [PSCustomObject] @{
                Line = $lineNumber
                Operation = $lineOperation
                Text = $_.InputObject 
            } | Format-Table -AutoSize

            Out-File -FilePath $resultFile -InputObject $results -append
        }
    }
}
```

However, I need to capture details of each parent element of each line that has changed, but this method only compares one line at a time.  I can't figure out how to then parse back through the parent elements to generate the XPath.

For example, this is the second XML file:

```
<root>
  <Asset>
    <Name>Platform</Name>
    <id>65168</id>
    <Department>
        <Name>Facilities</Name>
        <id>1f8504e9573b</id>
        <Type>
          <Name>HSE</Name>
          <ConfigurationId>HA68400</ConfigurationId>
        </Type>
    </Department>
  </Asset>
</root>
```

If I find that the <ConfigurationId> line is different.  Instead of outputting:

> <ConfigurationId>HA68400</ConfigurationId>

I want to output:

> Platform\Facilities\HSE

Comment: What have you tried so far? What worked and what didn't work? Show your code and you'll have a better chance of getting a useful answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for more info on asking questions that get better responses.

Comment: I've added some of my current code, but I think it might have to be changed.  The method I'm using now compares each line individually and I can't think of how to then parse back through previous lines to find the parent elements.  Maybe I'm on the wrong track altogether.

Comment: I’d take a different approach - parse both documents into ```XmlDocument```s then iterate through the ```Asset``` nodes in the first document, find the node with the same ```id``` in the second document and compare the ```ConfigurationId```s. If they’re different you can walk up the parent nodes to build your path for that ```Asset``` using the ```Name``` at each level.

Comment: Unfortunately the IDs may be different at every level.  I want to find all differences in the file, not just the ConigurationId differences.

Can you point me at something that will tell me how to iterate through nodes and find a particular nodes, and how to walk up the parent nodes?